# The place where to execute custom code while migration

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

Guys please advice. I'm release new version of software and there were some braking changes, to order properly update from previous version i need to execute custom code on applying certain migration. 
Update steps are:
1. Get all records from one table
2. Foreach thought them and create appropriate record in other tables
I prefer to use my "Manager" from business logic layer(core)

I don't know yet how to implements this. Please give me advice or code sample would be better. 
So far I see 3 places where I can put these logic. 
1. Migration file itself. in EF layer. 
2. Migrator project.
3. Seed file in EF layer.

Comment: I would recommend writing SQL for this operation and executing it in the migration file. Like so `migrationBuilder.Sql(``)`

Comment: I can't execute only SQL, because there are some code which sign file with RSA key and then save it to DB. So I need to call few method from my core layer anyway.

Comment: migrations are for schema migration, if you need to do a data migration you can create a dummy action, write your methods to change the data, fire the action, and delete the action. Since it's a data change, there is no point in persisting the actions as the data will be changing in the future.

Comment: For sure I can do this. But i'm curious is there any other way. To make it persistent

Comment: If it's seed data you can use `builder.Entity<T>().HasData()` in the model configuration, but if it's a one time transformation you can create a class for it that takes a DbContext object and does the transformation.

Answer (score 0):

According to @Avin Kavish recommendation I've created method in Migrator project with additional flag "-migrateToV2" and create method which use my manager from core to update data properly. Thanks.